# Can't the Time Stone be touched with bare hands?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, avengers-endgame

So throughout *Infinity War* and in the current *Endgame*, the Time Stone was never touched with bare hands, it seemed to be surrounded by a certain aura and gets transferred from person to person untouched.

Is there a special reason behind it?

[image]

Comment: I wondered this. The only possible exception is when the Ancient One gives the Stone to Bruce but we don't actually see it in his hand. She doesn't touch it either.

Comment: No infinity stones can be safely touched with bare hands until Endgame where apparently it's all cool and even Hawkeye can handle the Soul stone, and no one suffers any ill effects from handling them during the time heist

Comment: @GordonBennett Thanos can touch the soul stone with no ill effects. Vision can touch the Mind stone (unless he counts as a tool). Malekith can touch the liquefied Reality stone (unless it also would slowly kill him like Jane).

Comment: @GordonBennett Thanos had no reaction to holding the soul stone, either.  I think meeting the sacrifice requirement is already sufficient to hold the stone; that was literally what you did it for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are no official sources for this, just some theories and speculations:

One speculation says **it can be touched**, but just like the power stone, you will suffer the effects of touching an infinity stone (Maybe it kills you, vaporizes you, etc).

And that's why the [Eye of Agamotto](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Eye_of_Agamotto) was created:

> The Eye was created by Agamotto, using the Time Stone as a component to allow the user to safely wield it without directly touching it and suffering the adverse effects of touching an infinity stone. The container was created in the shape of an eye, hence its name. The mystical properties of the relic, as well as the spells and gestures necessary to use it

One other theory that I really like is that the stone represents **Time**, and time isn't really a physical thing that you can touch it.

Comment: You can't touch time, but your watch also represents time, which you surely can touch(or kick or throw)

Comment: @Vishwa I think a watch represents more like a passage of time or something, but I'm not sure...

Comment: mind blowing topic. we shouldn't discuss about time when we're sober ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not all the Infinity Stones are harmful to human touch. As seen on screen only the power, reality and space stones have been shown to be damaging to touch. And the space stone is only harmful when taken out of working machinery while it was being actively used.

With that said its possible that the time stone has the magical aura since we see it primarily handled by wizards when they take it or pass it, as Dr.Strange giving it to Thanos. The Eye then could be thought of as device to control and channel its powers. Like the Tesseract which housed the space stone, the power stone which requires a container separating it from organic matter to prevent it from setting off uncontrollably whenever it comes into contact, the Aether requiring a live host to thrive and function.

So putting the Time Stone into contact with a living being could have some unforeseen effect.

Answer (score -2):

Touching the space stone warps you away. Touching the power stone overloads you with power, killing weak beings.

Touching the time stone probably makes you infant or makes you old. That's why people choose not to touch it directly.

Comment: Touching the Reality stone (when it's the Aether at least) causes it to live inside you, and if you know how, to bring about eternal darkness.